# curl http://subtitle.co.il/browsesubtitles.php?cs=movies | grep -o -P '(?<=list.php\?mid=)\d+'

Tags: regex, bash, curl, grep

New to bash scripting, The previous answers didn't helped me.

I am trying to harvest ids from web pages and I need to parse `page1`, get a list of ids, and use them to parse corresponding web pages.

The thing is I'm not sure how to write the script...

Here's what I would like to do:

1. Parse `url1` according to `regexp`. Output: list of extracted ids (`101`, `102`, `103`, etc).
2. Parse each url with output id, for example: parse (`http://someurl/101`), then parse (`http://someurl/102`), etc.

So far, I have come up with this command:

```
curl http://subtitle.co.il/browsesubtitles.php?cs=movies | grep -o -P '(?<=list.php\?mid=)\d+'
```

The command above works, and gives a list of ids.

Any advice for the next steps? Am I on the right track?

Thanks!

Comment: Instead of using `curl` you could use `wget -q -O-`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're next step would probably do a loop on all ids:

```
parse_url () {
    for id in $(grep -o -P '(?<=list.php\?mid=)\d+' "$1"); do
        # Use $id
        url="http://someurl/$id"
        # or parse for the URL with the ID
        url="$(grep -o -P 'http://[a-zA-Z./%0-9:&;=?]*list.php\?mid=$id[a-zA-Z./%0-9:&;=?]*' "$1")"
        # Get page
        new_page_file="$(mktemp)"
        wget -q -O "$new_page_file" "$url"
        # Parse url
        parse_url "$new_page_file"
        # Delete old temporary file
        rm "$new_page_file"
    done
}

wget -q -O file.html http://subtitle.co.il/browsesubtitles.php?cs=movies
parse_url file.html
```

Here we have defined a function called `parse_url`, that iterates over all ids it finds in a file passed as an argument (ie. `$1` is the first argument passed to the function).

We can then use the ID to generate a URL, or we can grep the URL from the same file, now extracting the ID. Note that the regular expression for finding the URL assumes that the URL has a specific format:

1. It starts with "http://"
2. It only contains the characters that are used between the square brackets

To download the page, we create a temporary file with the `mktemp` command. Since you said you're new to bash scripting, I'll just give a quick explanation for the `$(...)`s that appears. They run a command or a series of commands that are specified between parenthesis, then execute them, capturing their standard output and placing it where the `$(...)` was. In this case, it is placed inside the double-quotes that we assign to a `$new_page_file` variable. Therefore `$new_page_file` contains the name of a random file name created for storing the temporary file.

We can then download the URL into that temporary file, call the function to parse it, and then delete it.

To call the function initially, we download the initial URL into a file `file.html`, and then call the function passing that file name as the argument.

EDIT: Added recursion, based on *Barmar*'s answer

Hope this helps a little =)

Comment: Hi, Janitu, thanks a lot for your reply, both your reply and Barmar's  really helped me understand bash functions better. so currently i have the following script:  parse_url() {
  ids=$(curl "$1" | grep -o -P '(?<=list.php\?mid=)\d+')
  for id in $ids
  do echo url1 extracted id:$id
     echo "http://subtitle.co.il/view.php?id=$id&m=subtitles#${id#1}"
  done
}
parse_url http://subtitle.co.il/browsesubtitles.php?cs=movies

Comment: Great! Glad I could help! If you need anything else, don't hesitate to ask =)

Comment: so, now that iv'e got the ids, im trying to catch the movie titles. i came up with the regex to do that, and tested it with regexr. but when i run the curl command to test if i get the titles, i get all the page, as if the grep is ignored: curl http://subtitle.co.il/view.php?id=1123506&m=subtitles#123506 | grep -o -P '(?<=style="direction:ltr;" title=")(.*?)(?=">)'
+ if i put this in a bash script, how do i exit the # sign in the url? thanks

Comment: Hi! You should enclose it between double quotes: `curl "subtitle.co.il/view.php?id=1123506&m=subtitles#123506" | ...`.

Comment: great! thanks! how do i loose all the transaction data that curl throws on screen? for example:   % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  2 59181    2  1271    0     0   1735      0  0:00:34 --:--:--  0:00:34

Answer (score 0):

This is a recursive algorithm, so you need to write a function:

```
parse_url() {
  ids=$(curl "$1" | grep -o -P '(?<=list.php\?mid=)\d+')
  for id in $ids
  do echo $id
     parse_url "http://someurl/$id"
  done
}
```

Call this function with the start page, and it will echo all the IDs found on that page, then recursively parse all the `http://someurl/ID` pages.

This just echoes all the IDs found in all the pages. If there's something else you want to do with the IDs found, you can pipe this script to that. Also, I don't do any duplicate suppression, so it's possible this script could loop forever if there are back-references between pages. You can keep track of the IDs that already have been seen in an array and check this before recursing.

Answer (score 0):

This kind of cli html parsing is exactly what I wrote my [Xidel](http://videlibri.sourceforge.net/xidel.html) for. (and it uses xpath instead of regexp, so you don't summon [Cthulhu](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1501222)... (too late, he is already there, i just went to my bathroom and there was this really strange sound...))

If you just need the ids to

> use them to parse corrosponding web pages.

you can just follow the links, instead of explicitly extracting the ids.

E.g. Print the titles of all linked pages

```
xidel 'http://subtitle.co.il/browsesubtitles.php?cs=movies' -f '//a[starts-with(@href,"list.php")]' -e //title
```

by following all links `//a`  whose destination `starts-with(@href,"list.php")`. (`-f` means follow links, `-e`: means extract data.)

Or if you want extract the large text block on the view url: (don't understand the language, no idea what it is saying...)

```
xidel 'http://subtitle.co.il/browsesubtitles.php?cs=movies' -f '//a[starts-with(@href,"list.php")]/replace(@href, "list.php[?]mid=", "view.php?id=")' -e 'css("#profilememo")'
```

Or if you really need the ids separately, you can extract them first:

```
xidel 'http://subtitle.co.il/browsesubtitles.php?cs=movies' -e '//a[starts-with(@href,"list.php")]/substring-after(@href,"mid=")' -f '//a[starts-with(@href,"list.php")]' -e //title
```

Or easier with a temporary variable `links` to store all links:

```
xidel 'http://subtitle.co.il/browsesubtitles.php?cs=movies' -e '(links:=//a[starts-with(@href,"list.php")])[0]' -e '$links/substring-after(@href,"mid=")' -f '$links' -e //title
```

Comment: hi Benito, thank you for your help.  i decided to try and use your tool, and keep the code gods satisfied :)  i downloaded xidel-0.5.src.tar.gz but how do i install and run it? thanks

Comment: First, you need FPC and [Lazarus](http://lazarus.freepascal.org/) to compile it. (and on Linux also openssl and [synapse](http://synapse.ararat.cz/doku.php/download)). Then open `programs/internet/xidel/xidel.lpi` in Lazarus and click on "Run". (perhaps you need to compile my internet tools library first, by opening components/pascal/internettools.lpk in Lazarus, and click on "Use >> \ Install".)

Comment: (that might become confusing, if you are not used to Pascal programming. Have you tried the binaries? The Windows versions runs on Windows and in wine. (although with Windows, you need to swap the '-single quotes and "-double quotes))